# Convert $\pi = 4 - \frac{4}{3} + \frac{4}{5} - \frac{4}{7} + \frac{4}{9} - \frac{4}{11} +....$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

How To Convert $\pi = 4 - \frac{4}{3} + \frac{4}{5} - \frac{4}{7} + \frac{4}{9} - \frac{4}{11} +....$
To A Sum

My Attempt:
$$ \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^i \frac{(4)(-1)^{j+1}}{i} $$ knowing that $i$ increments by $2$ and $j$ increments by $1$

Comment: I'm not sure what $N$ is in your attempt. In any case, here is a hint : every odd integer can be uniquely expressed as $2n+1$ for a given $n$. You should get a result with only one sum.

Comment: Oh I got it, so you mean I only need one some that contains the odd integers. So you mean something like this: $$ \sum_{i=0}^N = \frac{(4)(-1)^{i}}{2i+1}$$
and N is just an integer.

Comment: This looks correct, apart from the = sign. What's more what you wrote is a finite sum and the equality holds for the infinite sum (assuming it converges – which it does). Symbolically, I'd write it as $$\pi = 4\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^i}{2i+1}$$

Comment: Well the = sign was a typing mistake.
and about your sum I think there is something wrong about it. it outputs:
$$ 4\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2i+1} = 4(1 + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{11} +....) $$
which is not an approximation of $\pi$.
and i think the correct sum would be:
$$ \pi = 4\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{i}}{2i+1} $$

Comment: You're right, I had a typo (which I corrected since then).

Comment: Ah didn't see it. Anyway Thank You So Much.

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

Observe that $\frac {1 + (-1)^{n+1}} {2} $ is equal to $1$ for odd $n$ and $0$ for even $n$. If you just insert this in summation all the even terms will be zero.